# What is the difference between VoIP notifications and notification sent with apns-priority 10?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Here's what [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1) state:

> The priority of the notification. Specify one of the following values:
>
> 10–Send the push message immediately. Notifications with this priority
>   must trigger an alert, sound, or badge on the target device. It is an
>   error to use this priority for a push notification that contains only
>   the `content-available` key.
>
> 5—Send the push message at a time that takes into account power
>   considerations for the device. Notifications with this priority might
>   be grouped and delivered in bursts. They are throttled, and in some
>   cases are not delivered.

And about [VoIP](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html):

> Instead of persistent connections, developers should use the PushKit
>   framework—APIs that allows an app to receive pushes (notifications
>   when data is available) from a remote server. Whenever a push is
>   received, the app is called to action. For example, a VoIP app could
>   display an alert when a call is received, and provide an option to
>   accept or reject the call. It could even begin taking precursory steps
>   to initiate the call, in the event the user decides to accept.

Do I understand correctly that `apns-priority` defines message queuing at APNS side, and VoIP push type defines what happens on the device?

And what do they mean saying

> It is an error to use this priority for a push notification that contains only the `content-available` key.

Will APNS return an error or is it just a bad practice?

P.S. I use AWS SNS for sending notifications and it does not support customisation of `apns-priority`, but I am curious how it affects the process.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that even if your app is closed voip notification can wake your app for kill/suspended state and user notification just shows an alert without waking up your app for more refer.
[Apple documentation for pushkit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit)

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that `VoIP notification` will launch your app if it's not running or was killed from app switcher and you need to handle the notification in your code, while the `normal notification` will be shown immediately as local notification and will not start your app.

Comment: so the app will lunch automatically when VoIP notification received. or we need to do something more?

Comment: It will be launched automatically.

Comment: Hi can tell me how can i send push notification from a asterisk server. can i use AGI?

Comment: You can't. You must generate a VoIP certificate for a target app and use that on your push server.